# Add double lines between some rows in a dataframe R - Formatting

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I would like to display a R dataframe with double lines between some rows.

For example to separate groups as in the picture below :

[image]

I looked at the functions formattable and kable but I didn't find anything.

Comment: it's a good question but it could be handy to include what you tried using kable (if only to make it easier for others to copy/paste and tinker with)

Comment: You might try further searching. This looked promising: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/140

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution which works with Rstudio :

```
library(gt);   library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(Group = c("Tree", "Tree", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower"), Value = sample(c(1 : 20), 5));  

df %>% gt() %>% tab_row_group(group = "", rows = 1:2)
```

Which gives :

[image]

Unfortunately I work with Jupyterlab, and here is an extract of the output I get with it :

[image]

Comment: Upvoted. Good that you posted an answer to your question after searching. It's only a warning, not an error. What happens when you follow the specific advice given in the warning message?

Comment: When I change "group" to "label", I get the same with no warnings.

Comment: So all is good?

Comment: Not good because the output didn't change, just the warning disappeared. But I almost have another solution, I'll make a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

So with Jupyterlab It's almost good with this :

```
library(gt);   library(dplyr)

df = tibble(Group = c("Tree", "Tree", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower"), Value = sample(c(1 : 20), 5), Letter = letters[1 : 5]);  

kable(df) %>% group_rows(index = table(fct_inorder(df$Group)), label_row_css = "text-align: left; border-top: double") %>% as.character() %>% display_html()
```

which gives :

[image]

I just wish I could remove the groups title in bold (Tree and Flower).